How can I watch a package called ITFoxTec and figure out how it's being called?
I am using a wonderfully clean and simple .Net SAML package called ITFoxTec.
It works great, but my problem is, I have no idea how it's working.
When I added the library to my project, I added the following to the ConfigureServices section of my Startup.cs code file:
services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(Configuration.GetSection("Saml2"));
    services.Configure<Saml2Configuration>(saml2Configuration =>
    {
        var entityDescriptor = new EntityDescriptor();
        entityDescriptor.ReadIdPSsoDescriptorFromUrl(new Uri(Configuration["Saml2:IdPMetadata"]));
        if (entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor != null)
        {
            saml2Configuration.AllowedIssuer = entityDescriptor.EntityId;
            saml2Configuration.SingleSignOnDestination = entityDescriptor.IdPSsoDescriptor.SingleSignOnServices.First().Location;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("IdPSsoDescriptor not loaded from metadata.");
        }
    });

    services.AddSaml2();

Then I added an AuthController.cs class that I found on the ITFoxTec site.
It works great but I have no idea how it's working.
I stepped through the project in Visual Studio, and it somehow goes to the Login route ([Route("Login")] in the AuthController.
Then it automatically takes me to the URL I set for SingleSignOnDestination in my appSettings.json file.
But I can't figure out how it gets there.
The reason I'm asking, is because I don't want it to automatically go there when the user hits the site, I only want it to go there if the user presses a LOGIN button.
Could anyone help?
Thanks!


it automatically takes me to the URL I set for SingleSignOnDestination in my appSettings.json file.
But I can't figure out how it gets there.
The reason I'm asking, is because I don't want it to automatically go there when the user hits the site, I only want it to go there if the user presses a LOGIN button.

There are different ways to handle this, but I expect in your app it's through attributes. Look in your controllers, and if a controller has the [Authorize] attribute it will require the user to be logged in before they can continue. If you want to allow anonymous access to certain areas, you can remove the [Authorize] attribute from those areas. You should also be aware of the [AllowAnonymous] attribute, which can be used on individual actions within an authenticated controller.

I did some testing, and I found that if I comment out this line in Startup.cs, services.AddSaml2(); , it doesn't go to the AuthController.  But that doesn't really help because I need that line for the SAML part to work.  :(

And have you looked for the attributes I talked about?

I do have a AllowAnonymous at the top of my AuthController. Should I take that out?
